# Incorporating a verb phrase into a noun: "Object + を + Verb dictionary form + noun" (波を越す遊び) vs. "Object + Verb masu form + の + noun" (波越しの遊び)

Tags: verbs, adjectives, nominalization

Here's an example: 何も忘れてしまって**波越しの遊び**を続けさまにやっていました。

For the 波越しの遊び part, is there some nuance involved in writing it the way it is, versus writing it as 波を越す遊び?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 遊び is not the "subject" of the verb 越す, though.